# SelectSingleNode seems to search parents and siblings

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

I also think I'm confused about XPath usage.  I'm new to C# and XPath, so please be patient with me ;)

First, my XML file that I'm testing with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<testroot>
    <testnode>
        <name>Test Node 1</name>
        <things>
            <thing>
                <number>One</number>
            </thing>
            <thing>
                <number>Two</number>
            </thing>
        </things>
    </testnode>
    <testnode>
        <name>Test Node 2</name>
        <things>
            <thing>
                <number>Three</number>
            </thing>
            <thing>
                <number>Four</number>
            </thing>
        </things>
    </testnode>
    <testnode>
        <name>Test Node 3</name>
        <things>
            <thing>
                <number>Five</number>
            </thing>
        </things>
    </testnode>
</testroot>
```

So first I want to get the "testnode" that contains a "name" I'm interested in.  So I did the following, which worked correctly:

```
XmlNode testRoot = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/testroot/testnode[name=\"Test Node 1\"]");
```

Now I want to get all of the nodes under it that contain a "number" element.  According to my reading, I should be able to do this:

```
XmlNodeList testNodes = testRoot.SelectNodes("number");
```

But that yields an empty list.  The only way I got any results was to use //:

```
XmlNodeList testNodes = testRoot.SelectNodes("//number");
```

The problem is that seems to search all of the siblings and parents of the testRoot.  When I print everything out I get every node in the file that contains "number":

```
txtOutput.InnerHtml += "<p>" + testRoot.FirstChild.InnerText + "</p>";

foreach (XmlNode node in testNodes)
{
    txtOutput.InnerHtml += node.InnerText + "<br />";
}
```

> ```
> Test Node 1
> One
> Two
> Three
> Four
> Five
> ```

This behavior confuses me.  Am I using XPaths improperly, or does it normally search from the absolute root no matter which XmlNode you start with?

Comment: @ManSkirtBew: That's an abbreviated absolute expression. It would be expanded to `/descendant-or-self::node()/child::number`. Meaning: *from the document root of the context node through all its descendant nodes, select a child element with QName equal to `number`*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're trying to find *direct child nodes* called `number`. There aren't any of those - just one `things` element. If you want descendants, say so:

```
XmlNodeList testNodes = testRoot.SelectNodes("descendant::number");
```

The version with `"//number"` basically looks through *all* nodes in the document, hence your other result.

Having said all this, if you're using .NET 3.5 or higher I'd just use LINQ to XML and do all the querying in that. It's a much nicer API, IMO :)

Comment: Then, even if you start from a node different from root, does double-slashed `//xpath` search among all nodes ? It seems a bit strange to me...but good to know :)

Comment: @digEmAll: That's just part of XPath syntax. If you're going to stick with XPath, I suggest you find a good reference for it :)

Comment: You know, I thought I needed descendant::, but the page I was reading implied it was synonymous with //.  That fixed the problem instantly, thanks very much!

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I think it's a bit odd and a behavior belonging more to `XmlDocument` than to `XPath` syntax. In fact, if on the xml document you do: `doc.SelectNodes("/testroot/testnode[name=\"Test Node 1\"]//number")` it returns only the `<number>` nodes under the selected `"Test Node 1"`, not all in the document. So why it should be different starting from `"Test Node 1"` XmlNode instance ?

Comment: @digEmAll: The XPath documentation explains this a bit more clearly - it's *definitely* XPath behaviour. See http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev

Comment: @Jon Skeet: still not much convinced... I mean, why should `doc.SelectNodes("chapter[1]//para")` results be different from `doc.SelectSingleNode(chapter[1]).SelectNodes("//para")` ? They look the same to me... but perhaphs I have a strange way of thinking... :P

Comment: @digEmAll: Did you read the bit where `.//para` means something different to `//para`? I'm not saying it's a good idea - I'm just saying that's the way XPath is defined.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: ok, it's clear now. From my narrow point of view, performing a `SelectNodes` on a node instance implied the dot (.) even if not present. I was clearly wrong, thanks :)